# Using drop_while in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

Elixir's documentation states

```
drop_while(enumerable, fun)
   Drops items at the beginning of the enumerable while fun returns a truthy value
```

But I am confused with the below output.  Does it mean once it gets `!truthy` everything else is treated as false?

```
iex> Enum.drop_while([0,1,2,3,4,5], fn(x) -> rem(x,2) == 0 end)
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

I expected an output of `[1,3,5]` because

```
 iex> Enum.map([0,1,2,3,4,5], fn(x) -> rem(x,2) == 0 end)
[true,false,true,false,true,false]
```

I am trying to understand how it works rather than trying to get the output I want (there is `Enum.filter` to achieve the outcome)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `Enum.reject/2`, not `Enum.drop_while/2`. Like the documentation says, `Enum.drop_while` drops from the *beginning* until `fun` returns a truthy value. In your example, `fun` returns `true` for `1`, so you get all the elements of the original list starting at `1`.

```
iex(1)> Enum.reject([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], fn(x) -> rem(x, 2) == 0 end)
[1, 3, 5]
```

Comment: So, `until a truthy value` is the key to understand it.